Deploying firebase function and google server error
I am trying to deploy a google function.
npx firebase deploy --only functions:rewriter --project proj-staging --debug
this was working until a few hours ago.
now this command fail with

[2024-06-19T08:55:24.882Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/proj-staging/configs

That's an error.\n
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds. That's all we know.\n
Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0>
[2024-06-19T08:55:24.883Z] Got unexpected error from Runtime Config; it has no status code: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 {"name":"FirebaseError","children":[],"exit":1,"message":"Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0","status":500,"level":"debug"}


I tried
Removing the firebase function from firebase,
Clearing the packages on my cli and locally,
Updating firebase-tools to latest
Nothing works, and it's quite blocking.

This error is not something the volunteers of Stack Overflow can solve for you.  If you are getting this even after the suggested 30 second wait, you should reach out to Firebase support for assistance.
